# Binary stream library in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, serialization, binary-serialization, binarystream

Is there an equivalent in Objective C to C#'s BinaryReader and BinaryWriter? For example, a BinaryReader would take an `NSData*` object (or a generalised stream), and would have methods such as `-(uint32_t)readUnsignedInt`, `-(double)readDouble`, etc. A BinaryWriter would be symmetrical, and would work with `NSMutableData*` (or a generalised stream).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ended up writing a reader and writer for binary streams: https://github.com/vladimirg/objc-binary-stream-tools

Comment: I used your library but I'm getting a warning on GENERATE_METHOD(Int32, int32_t, uint32_t)//Values of type 'NSInteger' should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to 'long' instead                                                              and when i run it i get an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: @Legnus, nice to know somebody is using this! I don't have access to an x64 iPhone unfortunately, but I did fix the warnings. If you turn on exceptions breakpoints, run the test suite and tell me what the origin of EXEC_BAD_ACCESS is, that may help me fix the problem. You can open an issue for it on github.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, but it is very easy to write one.

I wrote a stream reader for decoding OWON Oscilloscope binary files.   See the OwStreamingDataParser class found in [this github repository](https://github.com/bbum/ow/tree/master/ow).   Creating the writer would be the same thing, but in reverse.   That should, at least, give you a start.

Note that if you are reading/writing graphs of Objective-C objects and only targeting iOS or OS X, then you can use [NSArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Easy - maybe, trivial - no :-( there are a few edge cases to handle, such as endianness (you assumed little endianness for int32 and host endianness for floats, right?). Maybe I should see this as an opportunity to write one and post it on github :-)

Comment: @VladimirGritsenko Yeah -- I made some endian assumptions that I'll likely regret once I start processing the data. :)  No, not trivial, as it'd require quite a bit more code.   Please do and share it (so I can leverage it in my code).

Comment: I'll try doing it over the weekend. For great justice!

Comment: Done, please see my answer to this question. Hope you find it useful!

Comment: @VladimirGritsenko Nice!  Note that `getError` should just be `error` or `lastError`.  Beyond that, looks straight forward!